# CSS ::first-letter pseudo-elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to do this using only this `<div>1 Hello, Welcome To Elzero Web School</div>`

[image]

I tried but I can't figure it out that is my code :

```
div{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(146, 141, 141);
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
}
div::first-letter {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The ::first-letter pseudo-element can only be applied to block-level elements.

The following properties apply to the ::first-letter pseudo- element:

- font properties
- color properties
- background properties
- margin properties
- padding properties
- border properties
- text-decoration
- vertical-align (only if "float" is "none")
- text-transform
- line-height
- float
- clear

source- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

That is why position is not working for the pseudo-element and in order to align the first-letter you can use margin properties to align it outside of your box

I tried to replicate design as close as possible you can take idea from the snippet to position the first-letter

```css
div{
    padding:25px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    font-size: 20px;
    border:20px solid white;
    display:inline-block;
}
div::first-letter {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:900;
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-right:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div>1 Hello, Welcome To Elzero Web School</div>
```

Comment: Please remember to cite your sources instead of copying without attribution https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the position of the `::first-letter` selector.
Here's a list of what you can change with it

- font properties
- color properties
- background properties
- margin properties
- padding properties
- border properties
- text-decoration
- vertical-align (only if float is 'none')
- text-transform (this controls text capitalization)
- line-height
- float
- clear

I'd suggest trying another approach

Comment: You can change the position using margin for example.